# Huge issue with MemoryErrors once I package up my application with PyInstaller. Garbage collection issue? Something else? I'm stumped

Tags: python, pyinstaller

### The Problem

The summarized problem is that I'm getting MemoryErrors thrown left and right when I package my application with PyInstaller. I suspect it has something to do with the main `queue` object not being garbage collected, however, I'm pretty in the dark here. It runs 100% OK when run from source and occupies only a few MB of memory. It's only once packaged that it balloons out of control.

### Program Overview

I have GUI application which provides image transformations of the desktop (basically silly effects), and (as an option) saves the recording of the screens to disk.

Being that Python's threads aren't truly concurrent, all the main pieces of the program run in a separate `multiprocessing` process, and communicate via shared `Queue` objects.

The basic setup is this:

[image]

It's basic producer/consumer. The ScreenMonitor produces snapshots of the screen, which get pushed into the queue so that they can be consumed by the ImageProcessor. The big throughput point of the program is the `queue` object. Just about *everything* relevant to the program is transferred though there -- and at the rate that the memory climbs, it's got to be getting backed up there.

As another data point, the program runs A-OK when run right from the source code. Even with the multiple processes and the heavy Image Processing going on, it occupies only a few MB of ram. Additionally, I've performed long, 4-5 hour stress tests to check for leaks and non are apparent. So, it's got to be something funny with PyInstaller.

#### Running from source

[image]

That's the programs memory footprint while running wide open, processing as much as it can as fast as it can.

#### Running Packaged Version

[image]

That's after letting it run for about 30 seconds. It'll spin off into a memory error after about 3-4 minutes.

### Some Code

Note: The below is heavily annotated, there was a ton of program book keeping I took out, so if the below looks buggy, or has a variable mismatch, it's due to the heavy editing. It's *not* production code is what I'm saying :)

Really, at it's core, it's a very basic [producer/consumer pattern](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/) . `Process2` puts image data into a queue, `Process2` operates on the images.

```
class Grabber(NoDaemonProcess):
    def __init__(self, in_queue, msg_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = in_queue
        self.ext_msg_queue = msg_queue
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.count = 0
        self.name == multiprocessing.current_process().name
        self.running = True

    def run(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        current = self.grab()

        img_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        image_processor = ImageProcess(img_queue, self.save_path)
        image_processor.start()
        
        clock = Clock()
        time.clock()
        while self.running:
            buffer_type, content, times = self.get(current, img_queue)
            self.img_queue.put((buffer_type, content, times))


class ImageProcess(NoDaemonProcess):
    def __init__(self, queue, save_path):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.in_queue = queue 
        self.save_path = save_path
        self.running = True
        # self.daemon = False

    def run(self):
        out_queue = Queue.Queue()
        threads = []
        for i in range(5):
            t = ImageSaver(out_queue)
            t.setDaemon(True)
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)
        # classmethod; effects all instances
        ImageSaver.setSavePath(self.save_path)

        while self.running: 
            queue_item = self.in_queue.get()
            buffer_type, content, times = queue_item
            # Do stuff with image stream..
```

So! Has anyone experienced this before? Is something in PyInstaller preventing the GC from running? As of now, I'm pretty stumped, and my app is more or less non-functional. Any ideas?

Comment: As a debugging step, what happens if you add `import gc; gc.enable()` on your startup? Does that help at all? You can check `gc.isenabled()` or explicitly tell python to do cleanup with `gc.collect()`

Comment: @gregb212 Just tested it out. Unfortunately no change in behavior. It still spins out of memory relatively quickly.

Comment: Do you have `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` in your code? You need that with pyinstaller or similar tools.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you manage to get to the bottom of this @ZackYoshyaro?